# Many errors trying to 'requests.get' for an API in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, get-request

Im trying to learn to access API's with python.
I am struggling to make it past even the first hurdle.

Following a tutorial i put:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://api.open-notify.org/astros.json")

print(response.status_code)
```

The open notify api was used as it is meant to be good for learning as its very simplistic.

Never the less the after running the script the all i get is the error message shown at the bottom of this post.

I am posting in the hope that someone has encountered this issue before and knows a solution, or that some one just knows the solution.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

LB

```
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\[Comp\Users\[user name]\Documents\TRF_Python> & C:/Users/[user name]/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe //
[Computer name]/Users/[user name]/Documents/TRF_Python/Test_API_V1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 978, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 309, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000019108B0F670>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 726, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.open-notify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /astros.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000019108B0F670>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//[Computer name]/Users/[user name]/Documents/TRF_Python/CompHous_API_V1.py", line 3, in <module>
    response = requests.get("https://api.open-notify.org/astros.json")
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.open-notify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /astros.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000019108B0F670>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\[Computer name]\Users\[user name]\Documents\TRF_Python> & C:/Users/[user name]/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe //
[Computer name]/Users/[user name]/Documents/TRF_Python/CompHous_API_V1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 978, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 309, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000025AD018F730>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 726, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.open-notify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /astros.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000025AD018F730>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//[Computer name]/Users/[user name]/Documents/TRF_Python/CompHous_API_V1.py", line 3, in <module>
    response = requests.get("https://api.open-notify.org/astros.json", timeout=None)
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.open-notify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /astros.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000025AD018F730>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\[Computer name]\Users\[user name]\Documents\TRF_Python>
```

Comment: Interestingly, I'm getting this on my local: `requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.open-notify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /astros.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1122)')))`

Comment: @rv.kvetch by any chance did you fix the issue you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

https://api.open-notify.org/astros.json gives a similar error in your browser. The problem is that it doesn't support HTTPS. http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json works.

There's an issue about this here: https://github.com/open-notify/Open-Notify-API/issues/9

Comment: personally I feel like this is **much** less secure. HTTPS should be mandatory for any API